# How to ignore particular log messages if already exists c#

Tags: c#, log4net

I am developing a windows form in c#,.Net 3.5. I am using log4net for displaying different log messages.
My log message look like:

> ERROR  15.11.2016 12:47:24 – Computer: SUPER, User:XYZ, Module: ServiceA, Method: loadSettings, [ERROR1001] Connectionlost
>
> ERROR  15.11.2016 12:47:34 – Computer: SUPER, User:XYZ, Module: ServiceA, Method: loadSettings, [ERROR1001] Connectionlost
>
> ERROR  15.11.2016 12:47:44 – Computer: SUPER, User:XYZ, Module: ServiceA, Method: loadSettings, [ERROR1001] Connectionlost

Is there any way to check whether log message already exist? I want to display the above message once if it occurs.

Here is my code:

```
private static void Log(string message, string type, string module)  
{
    try
    {
       sLogMessage = string.Format("Computer: {0}, User: {1}, Module: {2}, Method: {3}, [{4}] {5}{6}",
                                        System.Environment.MachineName, System.Environment.UserName,
                                        module, new StackTrace().GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name,
                                        type, message, Environment.NewLine);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
        
    switch (type)
    {
       case "DEBUG": logger.Debug(sLogMessage);
            break;
       case "INFO":
            try
            {
                logger.Info(sLogMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            break;
        case "WARNING": logger.Warn(sLogMessage);
            break;
        //here displays my error message and i want to check if it already exixts
        case "ERROR": logger.Error(sLogMessage);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, cache your error messages when received and check against them.  Not sure why you would only want to log it once a day though; you're losing one of the big benefits of logging if you do.  You would need to strip the timestamp from your message though before you compare.

Comment: i dont mean once a day lets say every 20 seconds or so ..

Comment: is there is any example of code

Comment: I think you need to have a think about whether this is the best approach first.  Why will only logging once a day help?  Surely you would want to know if you lose the connection more than once a day?

Comment: its not an issue with connection lost i have just written as example i just wanna ask if same ERROR mesage occur thousand times with an hour i just want to show message one time ...

Comment: @DeveloperSD If the same errors occurs thousand times, you ether not log it, or you have a problem within you code.

Comment: Use a List<Message> and use linq to find previous messages that meet all the same criteria. Systematically flush messages over and hour. I don't really see why this is a big task.

Comment: unfortunately i a just a developer and i have to do it

Comment: thank you steve is there is any example

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the lines of the log and search if they contain the log message and check their timestamp to match your condition, BUT without seeing the part where you attach the timestamp or the size in which the log grows this is sort of a wild guess..

In any case, it should be fairly simple to do something like this:

```
        string sLogMessage = "your Log message";
        DateTime yourTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        if (!File.ReadAllLines("PathToLogFile").Any(l => l.Contains(sLogMessage) && 
            (DateTime.Parse(l.Substring("extract the timestamp from the line")) - yourTimeStamp).TotalDays < 1))
        {
            //Add it to the log
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
private class LogMessage
{
  string module { get; set; }
  string message { get; set; } 
  DateTime LoggedOn { get;set;}
}
private List<LogMessage> messages = new List<LogMessage>();

private static void Log(string message, string type, string module)  
{
    /* remove any messages older than X time */

    if(messages.Where(x => x.module == module && x.message == message).Any())
    {
       // You can add more properties to the where for comparison
       // Already exist so return
       return;
    }

    messages.Add(new LogMessage() { module = module, message = message, LoggedOn = DateTime.Now});


    try
    {
       sLogMessage = string.Format("Computer: {0}, User: {1}, Module: {2}, Method: {3}, [{4}] {5}{6}",
                                        System.Environment.MachineName, System.Environment.UserName,
                                        module, new StackTrace().GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name,
                                        type, message, Environment.NewLine);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    switch (type)
    {
       case "DEBUG": logger.Debug(sLogMessage);
            break;
       case "INFO":
            try
            {
                logger.Info(sLogMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            break;
        case "WARNING": logger.Warn(sLogMessage);
            break;
        //here displays my error message and i want to check if it already exixts
        case "ERROR": logger.Error(sLogMessage);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Steve :-) will try this one thanks for ur help

Comment: You would need to expand on it a bit but it should do the job you need.

Comment: private List<LogMessage> messages = new List<LogMessage>();cannot create a list like this

Comment: sorryn it was static clss